# Difference between "happy birthday" vs "happiest birthday"

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

I have heard people saying "happy birthday" but "happiest birthday" sounds a little weird to me as it is the superlative form. Which would mean that only the recent birthday to be the happiest only, no? I'm confused :/ could someone please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: I have never heard the expression 'Happiest Birthday'. I have never heard anyone say 'This is' or 'That was' 'my happiest birthday'. In what context did you hear 'happiest birthday'?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong or weird about *Happiest birthday*. For example:

> It was my happiest birthday as I received more presents than I
>   expected.
>   Yesterday was the happiest birthday of my life.
>   I hope you
>   will have the happiest birthday with your fiance in London.

As you mentioned, *happiest* is the superlative form of the adjective *happy*. It doesn't mean it is the most recent birthday. If your happiest birthday was 10 years ago, you could say, "10 years ago today was the happiest birthday of my life."

However, you don't usually say "Happiest birthday to you." when you wish someone a happy birthday.

Comment: You could even say this for a future birthday, too. _Next Tuesday is your birthday. I hope it is your happiest birthday ever!_

Comment: The speaker used it for the most recent birthday. :/

Answer (score 0):

You would occasionally find "happiest birthday" as in [this book title](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Happiest_Birthday_to_My_Best_Friend_You/Rz9dzQEACAAJ?hl=en), which starts with "Happiest birthday to my best friend". What that means is simply "may this be my best friend's happiest birthday *yet*".

[A notebook planner](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Happiest_Birthday_to_the_BEST_Teacher_Ev/FH1nzQEACAAJ?hl=en)'s title starts with "Happiest birthday to the BEST teacher ever." Again, this means "may this be the happiest birthday the best teacher ever has had".

As others have commented, "happy birthday" is *way* more common, both in everyday speech and writing. You'd sometimes see "happiest of birthdays to you" on [greeting cards](https://emilymcdowell.com/products/happiest-of-birthdays-to-you-card). In summary, stick to "happy birthday", but be aware that on rare occasions  - and, it seems, primarily in writing - people might use "happiest" to with someone a **very** happy birthday.